# JHipster Authentication using OpenID-Connect

Tags: authentication, jhipster, openid-connect

I have been setup OpenID-Connect using MySQL Database and running when I test using Simple-Web-App.

Now I want create new website using JHipster with authentication connect to my OpenID-Connect Server.

What type of security should I use on JHipster?

- Social Login
- OAuth2 Authentication
- Token-based authentication

How to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JHipster project has had a good discussion on this subject [here](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-experimental-microservices/issues/3).

- That's not working out-of-the-box yet
- But someone has already done it and provided instructions

You should use OAuth2 authentication, and also have a look at the future [JHipster OpenID Connect](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-openid-connect).

Help on this subject is very welcome by the project, so if you can help or give feedback, don't hesitate to participate.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I will check on that and update the result!